# Why is my property not being released?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a lazily-loaded property defined as below, which seems to be retained every time I access it like `foo.bar`. After the 'for' loop exits (dispatched async from init) all the copies of `bar` get released, but in the meantime they all build up and I get memory warnings.

Why is this happening? Is ARC somehow never hitting [pool drain] internally to clean up unused memory? Or am I somehow causing a retain cycle with my dispatch or in a block?

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyAlgorithm *bar;

@end

@implementation Foo

- (id)init {

   if (self = [super init]) {

    __weak Foo *weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        weakSelf.testAudioFilePaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:kAudioFileWavType inDirectory:kTestFilesDirectory];

        for (NSString *path in weakSelf.testAudioFilePaths) {

            weakSelf.bar = nil; // this is so we rebuild it for each new path

            [weakSelf readDataFromAudioFileAtPath:path];

        }

    });
  }
  return self;
}

- (MyAlgorithm *)bar {
   if (!_bar) {
      _bar = [[MyAlgorithm alloc] initWithBar:kSomeBarConst];
   }
   return _bar;
}


@end
```

Comment: "which seems to be retained every time I access it like foo.bar" - because properties are too safe. You are allowed to use a property of an object even if the object itself is deallocated (provided that you've stored the property before the deallocation of the object); that's why the getters don't do `return _backingIvar;` but rather `return [[_backingIvar retain] autorelease];`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to wrap bits of the code **within the loop** in `@autoreleasepool` blocks, so that the pool is drained after every iteration of the loop, rather than at some future point after the loop exits:

```
- (id)init {

   if (self = [super init]) {

    __weak Foo *weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        weakSelf.testAudioFilePaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:kAudioFileWavType inDirectory:kTestFilesDirectory];

        for (NSString *path in weakSelf.testAudioFilePaths) {

            @autoreleasepool {

                weakSelf.bar = nil; // this is so we rebuild it for each new path

                [weakSelf readDataFromAudioFileAtPath:path];
            }

        }

    });
  }
  return self;
}
```